# What is the complexity of computing some problems related to real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, computational-complexity

I was thinking. I do not know whether my question has any sense.

- I want to know is there any way to compute analytically or explicitly some of the problems give below.
- What is the complexity of computing them?
- Is it worth to do it?

There are a lot of things that we know in mathematics especially in real analysis and we cannot compute explicitly such that:

1- Can anyone compute $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n^2}$ explicitly in function of $N$?

2- Can anyone find the integral of $e^{x^2}$, $\frac{1}{\text{log}x}$, $\dotsc$ explicitly?

There area a lot of other things that we all now.

Is it even necessary to compute them analytically? What is the real complexity of computing them?

Comment: For the second most of those are proved not to be in terms of elementary functions. I believe for all of those though they are computable numbers, so you can get arbitrarily close to the actual value if given enough computing time.

Comment: Can you please give me some references about the proofs of the second item?
Could someone spend time to (for example) try to get an explicit value of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n^2}$? Is it worth?

Comment: http://www2.maths.ox.ac.uk/cmi/library/academy/LectureNotes05/Conrad.pdf goes over some of the reasons why they can't be expressed in elementary functions. I honestly haven't looked to closely into it for a while so am not certain on how to prove it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help.

Comment: For the first part I'm not sure since I've never looked at the series. It obviously converges and maybe messing around with induction could provide some useful insight into how it grows(it is obviously monotonic increasing).